# Angular RC5 - Overridden component template fails to find input property

Tags: templates, angular

I have two components:

**IfNodeComponent**:

```
@Component({
    template: '<se-dynamic-condition (questionLinkClicked)="onQuestionClicked" [condition]="node.condition"></se-dynamic-condition>',
    selector: 'se-node-if'
})
export class NodeIfComponent {
    @Input() node: NodeProperties;

    onQuestionClicked(event: IQuestionLinkClickEvent): void {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

and **DynamicConditionComponent**:

```
@Component({
    template: '<p>My original template</p>',
    selector: 'se-dynamic-condition'
})
export class DynamicConditionComponent {
    @Input() condition: Condition;
    @Output() questionLinkClicked = new EventEmitter<IQuestionLinkClickEvent>();
}
```

I am writing a test to check that the `[condition]` binding is attached to the `se-dynamic-condition` component inside the if node template.  To do this I am overriding the template of the DynamicConditionComponent to simply be `{{condition | json}}`.  This then allows me to compare the JSON and assert that it is identical to the condition that should be passed in.

Before RC5 I used the `OverridingTestComponentBuilder` to achieve this.  But since I've just upgraded to RC5, I am rewriting that test to use the `TestBed` instead.  This is not going too well.  Here is how it looks:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [NodeIfComponent, DynamicConditionComponent]
    });

    TestBed.overrideComponent(DynamicConditionComponent, {
        set: {
            template: '{{condition | json}}'
        }
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NodeIfComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    element = fixture.nativeElement;

    component.node = {some:'data'};
    fixture.detectChanges();
});

it('should display a dynamic condition component and pass the condition to it', () => {
    let dc = element.querySelectorAll('se-dynamic-condition');
    expect(dc.length).toEqual(1, 'Dynamic condition component is found');
    expect(dc[0].innerHTML).toEqual(JSON.stringify({some:'data'}, null, 2));
});
```

However, running this test fails with the following error:

`Can't bind to 'condition' since it isn't a known property of 'se-dynamic-condition'.`

If I don't override the template for DynamicConditionComponent, then I don't get the error, but understandably my test fails.  And if I remove the property binding from the IfNode template, then I don't get the error, but again, the test fails as expected.  The error message points towards the `se-dynamic-condition` component not being registered in the same module.  But it is, and *the code works* when I run it.  It is just the test that is the problem, which doesn't use the module definition anyway.  That's what the `TestBed.configureTestingModule` statement is for.

So it appears that overriding a template also loses the condition property associated with the component.

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong here?  Examples I have seen elsewhere of overriding the template work fine, but I haven't seen any that override a template with an input property (and then try to assign a value to that property).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please add component.html content?

Comment: Ok, I've added the whole IfNode component and merged the template with it for clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in RC5 fixed in RC6 by  https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/10767

For now as a workaround re-specify the inputs in the override statement.

use

```
TestBed.overrideComponent(DynamicConditionComponent, {
    set: {
        template: '{{condition|json}}',
        inputs: ['condition'],
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Robert.  Disclaimer - Robert works with me but found the answer so gets the rep.  Leaving this here for any other unfortunate soul who has the same problem.